# How does bitwise NOT work at a low level?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitwise-not

I was curious as to how exactly the bitwise `NOT` operation performs inversion so efficiently and what it looks like 'under the hood' so I tried to implement it myself. As seen below:

```c
void bitwiseNOT(char* binaryString) {
    int binaryLength = strlen(binaryString);
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryLength; i++) {
        binaryString[i] = (binaryString[i] == '1') ? '0' : '1';
    }
}
```

This correctly inverts `binaryString` but is a lot less efficient than simply using the bitwise `NOT` operator (`~`), eg. by doing:

```
long int binary = 101010111010001011;
binary = ~binary;
```

What exactly happens at a low level that causes it to be quicker than my implementation?

Comment: In C `0101010111010001011` is a number in octal representation. So after `binary = ~binary` it will be `-2287543741579786` in decimal

Comment: @ryley -- as I tried to express in my answer, your function is slower because it isn't doing what C's bitwise not operator does. And now your function has been changed from when I wrote the answer. There are _many_ things that make your current function slower than `~`, including: your function represents bits as a string (of bytes), iterates over that string once when printing to `binaryString` with `sprintf`, once again  with `strlen`, once again in a `for` loop, once again when converting `binaryString` to an integer value with `strtol`.

Comment: C's bitwise `~` operator compiles (as described in my answer) to an assembly code instruction, i.e., the operand is loaded into a hardware register and a hardware instruction is applied to it. You can't implement this yourself, and you can't write a bitwise not function that will compete with a hardware instruction. You _can_ improve the performance of your `bitwiseNOT` function, but that is outside of the scope of your original question and you should post a new question for that.

Comment: @adabsurdum: you can write `binary = binary ^ -1;` (or whatever other way of writing a constant with all its bits set, which doesn't depend on the C implementation using two's complement).  That will either optimize to a `not`, or on some RISC CPUs is how `~` is normally implemented anyway (with a sign-extended immediate `-1`).  But yeah, it's basically a primitive operation; at a *low* level (inside the CPU), a separate NOT gate for every bit; NOT is the simplest gate.

Comment: @PeterCordes -- That is interesting. With no optimization switch the assembly generated by Clang used an `xor` instruction with `-1` instead of a `not` instruction for the Godbolt example linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP function `bitwiseNot` is entirely different from C's `~` operator. The OP function is operating on a string, while `~` operates on integer types.

What is done *"under the hood"* depends on the implementation, i.e., the C Standard does not specify *how* to implement `~`. But it is likely that an implementation will just emit an assembly code instruction to perform the bitwise not operation. The OP `bitwiseNOT` function is certainly [not compiling down to a single instruction.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d7rf5vfrK) At -O3 GCC compiles OP code to 155 lines of assembly code, while Clang compiles it to 85 lines. This is comparing apples to oranges since `bitwiseNOT` and the `not_wrapper` function below are doing different things, but the OP function generates significantly more assembly code than an application of C's bitwise `~` operator.

Looking at the [results of compilation on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jznqjf4PK), GCC and Clang seem to emit the same x86-64 assembly code at -O3 optimization for a simple wrapper function around `~`. In both implementations the `~` compiles down to a single `not` instruction after loading the data.

C function:

```
int not_wrapper(int x) {
    return ~x;
}
```

GCC 13.2:

```
not_wrapper:
        mov     eax, edi
        not     eax
        ret
```

Clang 17.0.1:

```
not_wrapper:                            # @not_wrapper
        mov     eax, edi
        not     eax
        ret
```